# How to Pass Textbox Name from module to module? VBA EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to pass a textbox name from one module to another and then assign a value to that textbox.

Here's what I  was trying.

```
Sub MyTest(txt as Textbox)
txt.value = 1
end sub

sub Try()
MyTest userform1.textbox1
end sub
```

Can someone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to do was change (txt as textbox) to (txt as control)
Thank you.

```
Sub MyTest(txt as Control)
txt.value = 1
end sub

sub Try()
MyTest userform1.textbox1
end sub
```

Comment: You should also be able to do it as `As MSForms.TextBox`